# How to create thousands of tables in SQL Server from the data in spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a spreadsheet with the information of 2600 tables (includes `column_name`, `data_type`). Now how should I create a SQL query to create 2600 tables from Excel in my database?

Comment: One way: Export each worksheet to a CSV file and then import those files into your SQL database.

Comment: Why do you have so many tables? Do any of these tables share the same design? Are you using separate tables as a way of achieving horizontal or vertical sharding - or is this data that represents 2600 different distinct business entity types?

Comment: seriously! 2600 tables? r u creating 1 table for each column?

Comment: What do the CSV files look like? Do these CSV files only represent the table design, or do they represent the table data?

Comment: I have 2600 distinct tables.  They represent only table design.

Comment: Can you show an example of a worksheet that has the table definition?

Comment: Duplicate of [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/49fdab7c-6006-4d34-a349-1d88bfff1db1/how-to-create-thousands-of-tables-in-sql-server-from-the-data-in-spreadsheet?forum=transactsql). Rude and wasteful to post the same question independently to multiple forums.

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the sheets have got the same schema. I would suggest you to follow below steps to achieve this.

1. Create an SSIS package, which reads from Excel file multiple sheets into a single table in target database. [Loading Multiple sheets to a single table in SSIS](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/395541/how-to-load-data-from-multiple-excel-sheets-to-any)
2. Create a dynamic sql in TSQL, which reads from the above loaded table and generate DDL statement for creating table.